# WebGL drawArrays with invalid mode is not generating a error

Tags: javascript, webgl

So, in the middle of my code I invoke:

```
gl.drawArrays(381,3,0);
gl.getError();
```

And the getError() call returns 0.
What may cause this weird behavior?

Edit: I  am using chromium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's not an error. You are telling it to draw 0 elements starting at vertex 3 (your geometry type, 381, may or may not be valid but I doubt it's checking that just yet.)

I would imagine that internally it looks at your request to draw 0 elements and says... "Okay, done! I drew nothing, just like you asked!" and then moves on. Seems like a logical place to early terminate.

Try calling something really weird like this, see if it gives you an error then:

```
gl.drawArrays(-1,-1,2);
```

Comment: Your answer solved the issue, I switched count and first arguments. Off-topic:You are the gl-matrix guy, nice to meet you.